# Upload files from multiple subfolders with gsutil

Tags: gsutil

I need to "move" all the content of a folder, including its subfolders to a bucket in Google Cloud Storage.

The closest way is to use gsutil -rsync, but it clones all the data without moving the files.

I need to move all the data and keep data only in GCP and not in local storage. My local storage is being used only as a pass-thought server (Cause I only have a few GB to store data on local storage)

How can I achieve this?
Is there any way with gsutil?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the data to a bucket and reclaim the space on your local disk, you need to use `mv` command for example:

```
gsutil mv -r  mylocalfolder gs://mybucketname
```

`mv` command copies the files to a bucket and delete them after the upload.

Comment: Thanks. But this command don't copy subfolders. Do you know if is it possible to include all subfolders?

Comment: @CristianAvendaño if your sub-directory is empty this is an expected behaviour since cloud storage doesn't handle folder structures as local filestorage the full name of an boject is on this way `folder1/sfolder/filename.txt`


https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#object-names

Comment: @CristianAvendaño if rsync works well, you only need to delete your folder after the copy, MV command is not an atomic operation as is mentioned in the documentation  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#non-atomic-operation

Comment: Thanks. rsync works well, but I don't know how to delete only the files that has been copied. What if I have an error? I can't find a way to detect if the copy has been sucessful or not, and if sucessful, delete the file.

Comment: I've noticed that the -r do the trick with mv: gsutil mv -r C:\Source gs://DestinationBucket. If I put C:\Source\ didn't work. The last backslash was causing the trouble.